# IntelliJ restyled my own code style while pressing automatic completion key

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a question that bothers me for a long time, here some code as below,

```
if (flag) {
     // some code here
}
else | // cursor here
```

when I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (on Mac) to complete automatically, it restyled my code as

```
if (flag) {
     // some code here
} else {
     | 
}
```

and I just wanna it complete but never effect on my own style, i.e.

```
if (flag) {
     // some code here
}
else {
    |
}
```

is there any settings about this manner for IntelliJ IDEA? thanks in advance:)

Comment: Why?  IntelliJ's approach is so much prettier...

Comment: In order for it to correctly complete or modify your code style. I would assume it needs to know your code style. That should be configurable in Settings.

Comment: I'm afraid I just have little code eccentricity:P @Makoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a setting in your code style that had forced this.  By default, IntelliJ does not force the `else` statement to go to a separate line.

Navigate to Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java, select the Wrapping and Braces tab, and tick the "'else' on new line" checkbox.  This will then force all of your else statements to be on their own separate line as you wish.